# Pass link from JSON to React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a little problem, I need to pass a link from JSON to react, but I don't know how to do it. When I pass a link using {post.link}, it doesn't take me to the given address and reloads the entire react component

I know that links in JSON are empty, but when I add any link, the problem persists.

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "name": "",
        "price": "",
        "desc": "",
        "link": "",
        "tags": ""
    },

    {
        "name": "",
        "price": "",
        "desc": "",
        "link": "",
        "tags": ""
    }
]
```

**REACT**

```
import React from 'react';
import productdb from './productdb.json';

function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="posts">
        {productdb.map(post => {
          return (
            <>
              <h4>{post.name}</h4>
              <p>{post.desc}</p>
              <p>{post.price}</p>
              <a href="I need paste link here"></a>
            </>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Try href={post.link} target="_blank"

Comment: Now everything works, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

test this code

```
href={'/' + post.link}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `"I need paste link here"` with `` `${post.link}` ``. It think it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
<a href={`/${post.link}`}></a>
```

But I would suggest using `Link` or `NavLink`

By using `react-router-dom` `Link` or `NavLink`, reloading of the page won't happen

Answer (score 1):

Pro tip: Use full links in your json data.
example-> use "https://www.google.com" instead of just "www.google.com"

I used <a href={`${post.link}`}> . It worked fine after i used full length links in my json data, else it won't work.